# Solspace Freeform: return to anchor in page when having inline errors

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a contact form set up with Freeform and when having inline errors, I would like to return to an anchor on the page, since my form is on the bottom of the page.

I tried setting inline_error_return="#contact-form", but it doesn't even add the hash to the url.

Hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think inline_error_return is the way to go, but maybe you need a complete url there, not just the anchor. In a recent site I did, I have inline_error_return="{page_url}/#job-apply-form" which works.

Comment: Yes, you need the URL or segments *as well as* the anchor in `inline_error_return=""`, eg. `inline_error_return="template_group/template#anchor"`. Keep in mind that the page is reloaded with the inline errors, so the anchor behaviour is a bit different from the classic way of clicking a link going to an anchor on the same page.

Comment: A really late addition - You can use `inline_error_return="{current_url}/#anchor"` too. Handy if your form is outside the channel entries loop.